# issue related to autopostback in DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have dropdownlist and set autopostback Property to true..
the problem is that i when i change index of dropdown list Page gets postback. After Completion of Page load index of dropdown goes to 0 automatically.

How can i remain index of dropdownlist after POstback

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the drop down only in the page load.

```
if(Page.IsPostBack == false) //page is loading first time
{
    //you can do your coding here.
}
```

for more infor refer to [what is Ispostback == false ?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1383878.aspx/1)

EDIT:

You have to set [DataValueField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield.aspx) and [DataTextField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield.aspx) of the dropdown list, before binding the dropdownlist may be.

Answer (score 3):

Check weather the ViewState is enabled for the dropdown control & web page.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are not binding you check box again

to bind dropdownbox one time write code

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
  //bind you drop downbox 
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your anwer but problem is not related to IsPostback property,.. I have added Static Items in dropdown list. but when user select any value from the dropdownlist the page reloads but Item doesn't change in the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 1):

```
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
          // get selected value 
        }

or (Page.IsPostBack)

{
   //get selected value
}
```

not sure how you use it but you have to control postback

Comment: Hi Thanks for your anwer but problem is not related to IsPostback property,.. I have added Static Items in dropdown list. but when user select any value from the dropdownlist the page reloads but Item doesn't change in the dropdownlist.